# Nondimensionalize differential equation $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{l}sin\theta=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given the differential equation of the motion of a pendulum:

$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{L}\sin\theta = 0$

How does setting $w=\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}$ and $\tau = wt$

give

$\frac{d^2\theta}{d\tau^2}+\sin\theta = 0$

?

Answer (score 2):

$$\tau=wt $$
$$\frac{d\tau}{d\theta}=w\frac{dt}{d\theta}\Rightarrow w\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$

$$w\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}=\frac{d\theta}{dt} \Rightarrow w\frac{d^2\theta}{d^2\tau}\cdot\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\frac{d^2\theta}{d^2t}$$

Since $\frac{d^2\theta}{d^2t}=-\frac{g}{L}\sin(\theta)$ and $\frac{d\tau}{dt}=w$

$w\frac{d^2\theta}{d^2\tau}\cdot w=-\frac{g}{L}\sin(\theta)$

$$\frac{d^2\theta}{d^2\tau}=-\sin(\theta)$$